# Algorithms for drawing hyperbolic tilings

Tags: algorithms, hyperbolic-geometry, art

I was looking at hyperbolic tilings on the Poincare disc model [like these](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/poincare/poincare.html) the other day, and I wondered how I might make my own. I have a basic understanding of what hyperbolic space is and how it works, but I would like to know if there are any algorithms to create these tilings. I'm sorry if this question is too vague, but help is appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125088/how-to-generate-tessellation-cells-using-the-poincare-disk-model?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: Sort of, but how do I draw a hyperbolic line?